# How to compare a string value to a Hash value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, asp.net-web-api

I have created an API controller that compares the username and password I typed versus the username and password(HASHED) that is saved on my database.

My problem is that is I'm really having a hard time comparing the password I typed because the password on my database is on a HASH state. They will obviously have two different values. How can I compare a my string value to a Hash value?

If the two password matched, it should return 'true' otherwise false. 
I'm on a confusing stage right now. Hope you can help me. Thanks.

These are the codes I have used.

**LoginController.cs**

```
namespace WebFormsDemo.Controllers
{
    public class LoginController : ApiController
    {
        private EBMSEntities db = new EBMSEntities();

        // GET: api/Login           
        [Route("api/Login/Search/{username}/{password}")]
        [ResponseType(typeof(List<AspNetUser>))]    
        public bool getUserPassword(string username, string password)       
        {              
            var hashedPassword = "";
            hashedPassword = Crypto.HashPassword(password);    

            var user = (from u in db.AspNetUsers
                                     where u.UserName.Equals(username)
                                     && u.PasswordHash.Equals(hashedPassword)
                                     select u).ToList();    

            if (user.Count() != 0)
            {
                return true;
            }    
            return false;    
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what's wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: @Rohit earlier I forgot to right the Crypto.HashPassword in my hash function.

Comment: You should have a look at Identity, which is a token based authentication - http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple techniques provided to hash the password strings. A few of them are MD5, SHA1, SHA256 etc. and many more that contain even complex function codes to make sure the passwords are less vulnerable to reverting back to string. Now, the problem *might be* that you are using a wrong version of hashing algorithm.

I would rather leave this code to the ASP.NET Membership itself, there is a function [`Validation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.validateuser(v=vs.110).aspx) in the [`Membership`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership(v=vs.110).aspx) class object that can be used to ask ASP.NET to verify if the user is valid. Then, your code would like this,

```
public bool getUserPassword(string username, string password)       
{              
    return Membership.ValidateUser(username, password); 
}
```

This would be managed by ASP.NET itself, and you will get what you want! If not, then I would recommend checking the hash algorithm and making sure, you are using the same hash algorithm that was used to hash the initial user password. Otherwise, it will always be different.

In the case of ASP.NET Identity, you can use [`UserManager.CheckPassword(user, password)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn497468(v=vs.108).aspx) to determine if the password is correct for the user. Since ASP.NET Identity is the recommended framework (and Membership is older one), the following code is recommended way of doing this using UserManager.Find(user:

```
public bool getUserPassword(string username, string password) {
    var user = UserManager.Find(username, password);
    return user == null; // If user is null, password didn't match.
}
```

This way, you will be able to do this. Finally, you can find good and helpful material on MSDN documentation for a full review of these functions.

Comment: Sir actually I don't know the hash algorithm for MVC 5 but that's what i'm using. What I want to do is just to compare the key in password and the password on my database. But my password on the database is in a hash value. Is there anyway I can compare my password to the hashed password?

Comment: @JayceeEvangelista, you might have misunderstood my answer. **The hash cannot be converted back to the plain-text**. That is why, each time a user login is initiated the plain-text password is also converted to hash value. The hashes for the same password (same case too!) are always same. That is how these systems log you in. That is why I provided you with the framework functions; which are easier to work with.

Comment: O I get it now. Thanks for that. But Sir based on my research. I'm using an 
ASP.NET Identity. In this case what should I do?

Comment: @JayceeEvangelista, do what I told. Use ASP.NET's built in codes. :-) They are really very extensible functions available in the library itself. Basically, what ASP.NET provides is a very easy framework to deal with, on the other hand have a look at a web authentication service created by me, https://www.nuget.org/packages/LoginKeys/, not so cool I would say. Requires a lot of modification, tweaking etc. My recommendation is to use ASP.NET Identity to perform all of the actions on the system for authentication and authorization of the users. I hope I am clear enough, Jaycee. :-)

Comment: Alright Sir. Thanks for that. Hope I can do it now.

Comment: Man I used Crypto.HashPassword to hash the password key in by the Customer, I don't know if it's an ASP.NET Identity class. The codes you provided doesn't seem to work. There's an error when I use UserManager.\

Comment: @JayceeEvangelista, no that is not ASP.NET Identity. That is a web helper in ASP.NET. Secondly, `UserManager` is a type, are you including the namespaces, references? What is the error?

Comment: @JayceeEvangelista, it is a built in class for the ASP.NET Identity.

Answer (score 0):

*From comment below answer:*

> Sir actually I don't know the hash algorithm for MVC 5 but that's what i'm using.

It sounds like you are using [Asp.Net Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity). In that case you should be using the provided framework including the [UserManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613290(v=vs.108).aspx) and/or [SignInManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn896559(v=vs.108).aspx) to validate the credentials.

<strike>Return first the user and then compare the password in memory. That is easier than doing it on the database.</strike>

```
var doesPasswordMatch = false;

var user = db.AspNetUsers.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserName == username);
if(user != null)
{
    var hashedPassword = Crypto.HashPassword(password);
    // var doesPasswordMatch = //compare u.PasswordHash with hashedPassword in memory
}
return doesPasswordMatch;
```

You will still need to convert the persisted password to the same format. It is unclear whether this is a byte array or something else. The best option is to abstract this to a different utility class. Also it is unclear on how you are hashing your password (what is the algorithm). Make sure you are using a secure hashing technique WITH a salt (that varies per hashed password).

Comment: Sir actually I don't know the hash algorithm for MVC 5 but that's what i'm using. What I want to do is just to compare the key in password and the password on my database. But my password on the database is in a hash value. Is there anyway I can compare my password to the hashed password?

Comment: @JayceeEvangelista - so are you using ASP.NET Identity (default) with MVC5 or something else? Whatever it is you are using there should already be a wrapper around the whole check user & password match that you can call with the plain text password which that wrapper will then convert and compare.

Comment: I'm using ASP.NET Identity with my Web API 2 Controller with acitions, using Entity Framewoek.

Answer (score -1):

Apply the same hashing function on the password received from the user. You can then compare between the two hashed passwords. If they are the same, then the password is correct.

Since you are using Identity, you can use `UserManager.PasswordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword()`. You need to send the hashed password from the database as the first parameter and the password given by the user as the second parameter.

```
public bool getUserPassword(string username, string password)       
{   
    string hashPassword= (from u in db.AspNetUsers
                        where u.UserName.Equals(username)
                        select u.PasswordHash).ToString();
    //Get the salt from the hashed password and use it to hash the user given password
    //Then verify that both the passwords match and check the result with the PasswordVerificationResult enum
    if (UserManager.PasswordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(hashPassword, password) != PasswordVerificationResult.Failed)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

The `VerifyHashedPassword` returns a type [PasswordVerificationResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.passwordverificationresult(v=vs.108).aspx) which is an enumeration that can be used to check whether the given password has failed or passed verification.

Alternatively the `SignInManager.PasswordSignIn()` or [`SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt173779(v=vs.108).aspx#M:Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.SignInManager%602.PasswordSignInAsync(System.String,System.String,System.Boolean,System.Boolean)) methods can be used if you're only looking to make the user sign in. Both methods have the same signature

Comment: It was an honest mistake. I have changed the codes Sir but it's still the same.

Comment: How can I use the 'UserManager'? It's an error. Is this something to do with the Library?